# IOS: AFNetworking's AFHTTPSessionManager.m dataTaskWithHTTPMethod method, URL and BASEURL not appending

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, afnetworking

I'm using Cocoapod Version 1.2.0 and AFnetworking 2.6.3

In AFHTTPSessionManager.m file,URLString returning string as NIL in  dataTaskWithHTTPMethod method.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:method URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters error:&serializationError];
```

I made a break point and it returns correct values in URLString and Base URL separately but once I enter to the mentioned code.

URLString returns Nil value to the requestWithMethod method.

```
NSString *appendedStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.baseURL,URLString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:method URLString:[NSURL URLWithString:appendedStr] parameters:parameters error:&serializationError];
```

Once I use the above code, it gets appended and values passes perfectly to the next method.

What would be the mistake?

Comment: Is the question really related to AFNetworking, or is it more between `NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString];` and `NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.baseURL,URLString]];`? If that's the case, then for instance, how is constructed self.baseURL and URLString? They have "/" at start/end?

Comment: The thing is with the 1st code block here which i mentioned and its a pod files code[AFHTTPSessionManager.m]. where im not suppose to change any thing.after a while I found that URLString Passes with Nil value because BaseURL and Urlstring doesn't append..
Then I have Unlocked the pod files code[AFHTTPSessionManager.m] with 2nd code Block, Where I got URLString with Valide URL. HereBy the Problem is with the AFNetworking